# Incorporating Fade into addClass jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, fade, addclass

I have this simple code:

```
$('.featureItems li').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover') }
)
```

How can i incorporate a fade effect, so the add/remove class is a little more gradual?

Would i require animate()?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "so the add/remove class is a little more gradual" do you want to delay adding the class?

Comment: Have you considered using CSS3 transitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're also using jQuery UI, it improves the CSS add/remove methods so that they accept a second parameter that's a delay (in milliseconds) to animate the CSS change over.  To animate the change over a half-second, for example:

```
$('.featureItems li').hover(
   function(){ $(this).addClass('hover', 500) },
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover', 500) }
)
```

**Update:**

To prevent the animation queue from getting jammed up or inconsistent during quick hover in/out sequences, you can also force existing animations to stop before starting the add/removeClass:

```
$('.featureItems li').hover(
   function(){ $(this).stop(true).addClass('hover', 500) },
   function(){ $(this).stop(true).removeClass('hover', 500) }
)
```

Comment: I would accept this but i tried implementing it but when moving over multiple elements, the removeClass would sometime not work, leaving the hover class on!

Comment: @benhowdle89: I've run into that before.  Usually, aborting any presently-executing animations before applying a new one will fix that.  See the update to my answer for an example.

Comment: This is not working at all. Because addClass and removeClass, both function do NOT have duration as argument!!!!

Comment: @MatildaYiPan: This assumes that you're using jQuery UI, which adds  this optional parameter to add/removeClass.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Dave Ward's answer, there's a **[standalone plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class)** which does this in case you don't want to use **jQuery UI**.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **@Dave Ward**'s answer, I had to remove the `stop(true)` part for the removeClass(), otherwise after the first mouseover/mouseout the mouseover part stops working:

```
$('.featureItems li').hover(
   function(){ $(this).stop(true).addClass('hover', 500) },
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover', 500) }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, non-javascript, alternative to this would be to change: `.featureItems li` in your CSS to have the following properties:

```
.featureItems li {
    transition: transform 1s, background-color 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s, background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s, background-color 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s, background-color 1s;
}
```

Which would then let CSS3 navigate between whatever changes you make in `.hover`, for example:

```
.hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
    transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    -o-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

You can find more info about CSS3 Transitions here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: I think this is the best answer, keeping in mind that presenation should live in CSS as much as possible. Fading elements fall under presentation.